# Why my linux doesn't display last login date?

Tags: ssh, sshd

On Debian Jessie (latest).

`sshd_config` is clearly:

```
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
```

But when I login to it from PuTTY, it failed to display the time.

```
login as: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Authenticating with public key "imported-openssh-key"
XXXXXXXX@XXXXXXXXXXXX:~$ _
```

Any ideas? I'm a IT developer and other servers are working as intended.

Comment: Please add mote details, unix version, distro...

Comment: what does /var/log/secure show?  do you have pam_lastlog configured as well as the SSH having the default PrintLastLog enabled? is the only problem that it won't show the time? in that case it could be something with  NTP

Answer (score 2):

The lastlog is printed by PAM using `pam_lastlog` module. If it is not in your PAM stack in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` (nor in other included files from there), you can add the lines like:

```
session     [default=1]   pam_lastlog.so nowtmp silent
session     optional      pam_lastlog.so silent noupdate showfailed
```

(taken from my `/etc/pam.d/postlogin` on Fedora 25)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've restarted sshd since adding that line. If it still doesn't work, try commenting out the line and restarting sshd because printing the last login date is default behavior without that line. And just in case, double check to make sure you're editing sshd_config and not ssh_config by accident.