# Debian doesn't display last login date?

Tags: debian, ssh, sshd

Related to [Why my linux doesn't display last login date?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/348620/why-my-linux-doesnt-display-last-login-date)

There's no "pam_lastlog" lines on BOTH servers' /etc/pam.d/sshd file.
But "Machine 2" output the time. (and Machine 1 don't).
The only differences are(sshd_config):

> (1) LOGIN BY PUBKEY
>   PubkeyAuthentication yes
>   AuthorizeKeysFile /xxxx
>   PasswordAuthentication No
>
> (2) LOGIN BY USER+PASS ('PasswordAuthentication Yes' is not exist)
>   PubkeyAuthentication No

Of course, I always update them using apt-get. Why this is different?

> (1)
>   :~$ lastlog
>   /var/log/lastlog: No such file or directory
>   :~$ sudo su
>   :~# lastlog
>   /var/log/lastlog: No such file or directory
>   uname -a
>   Linux X 3.16.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1+deb8u1 (2017-02-22) i686 GNU/Linux
>
> (2)
>   :~# lastlog
>   Username         Port     From             Latest......
>   uname -a
>   Linux X 3.16.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1 (2016-12-30) i686 GNU/Linux
>   apt-get dist-upgrade
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: "*If it is not in your PAM stack in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` (nor in other included files from there)*". Did you try to add that in your `/etc/pam.d/sshd`?